# Oracle PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, plsql

The problem I have is that in a loop I get the numeric or value error for using NUMBER's. The test data im using for LR_UPDATE_ROWS consists of 2 elements currently. Both are of the NUMBER type. The type of LR_UPDATE_ROWS itself is a PL/SQL table type, which consist of a NUMBER(3,0) column.

The code is as follows:

```
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LR_UPDATED_ROWS.FIRST); /* Prints out 1 */
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LR_UPDATED_ROWS.LAST);  /* Prints out 2 */
        a := LR_UPDATED_ROWS.FIRST; /* Assignment works */
        b := LR_UPDATED_ROWS.LAST;  /* Assignment works */
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a);  /* Prints out 1 */
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(b);  /* Prints out 2 */

        IF LR_UPDATED_ROWS IS NOT NULL THEN
            IF LR_UPDATED_ROWS.FIRST = 1 AND LR_UPDATED_ROWS.LAST = 1 THEN
              lv_rows_lst:=lv_rows_lst||','||LR_UPDATED_ROWS(1);
            ELSE
              FOR I IN LR_UPDATED_ROWS.FIRST..LR_UPDATED_ROWS.LAST
              LOOP
                lv_rows_lst:=lv_rows_lst||','||LR_UPDATED_ROWS(I);
              END LOOP;
            END IF;

            lv_rows_lst:=SUBSTR(lv_rows_lst,2,LENGTH(lv_rows_lst));
            OPEN LS_CUR FOR 'SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT_QUEUE DQ WHERE DQ.ENV_ID IN ('||lv_rows_lst||')';
        ELSE
            LS_CUR := LS_CUR;    
        END IF;
```

The row: „FOR I IN LR_UPDATED_ROWS.FIRST..LR_UPDATED_ROWS.LAST“ gives me the error:"PL/SQL: numeric or value error“.
All that my research from the web revealed about this error was that it was some sort of conversion or number size incompatibility error. Unfortunately I have been unable to understand in which way.

All help and hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Try this.

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LR_UPDATED_ROWS.FIRST);
    /* Prints out 1 */
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LR_UPDATED_ROWS.LAST);
    /* Prints out 2 */
    a := LR_UPDATED_ROWS.FIRST;
    /* Assignment works */
    b := LR_UPDATED_ROWS.LAST;
    /* Assignment works */
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a);
    /* Prints out 1 */
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(b);
    /* Prints out 2 */
    IF LR_UPDATED_ROWS.EXISTS(1) THEN
/* Still not getting the use of this piece of code */
      IF LR_UPDATED_ROWS.FIRST = 1 AND LR_UPDATED_ROWS.LAST = 1 THEN
        lv_rows_lst           :='SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(LR_UPDATED_ROWS)';
      ELSE
        FOR I IN LR_UPDATED_ROWS.FIRST..LR_UPDATED_ROWS.LAST
        LOOP
          lv_rows_lst:=lv_rows_lst||','||LR_UPDATED_ROWS(I);
        END LOOP;
      END IF;
      lv_rows_lst:=SUBSTR(lv_rows_lst,2,LENGTH(lv_rows_lst));
      OPEN LS_CUR FOR 'SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT_QUEUE DQ WHERE DQ.ENV_ID IN ('||lv_rows_lst||')';
    ELSE
      LS_CUR := LS_CUR;
    END IF;
```